# part.isMimeType == "Multipart/*" Does it mean it has an attachment?

Tags: android, attachment, mime, multipart

I have an email project in Android and I can receive and download my mails and its attachments but now I want to learn if a message has an attachment or not, and how many attachments it has got.

I mean I just need to do an if clause like:

```
if(messages[i].hasAttachment)
{
   int numberOfAttachments = messages[i].attachmentNumber;
  // do smthng
}
else
{
  // do smthng
}
```

Maybe its help: I am receiving my body part with this code sample. Meanwhile, as per my subject, if the isMimeType = "Multipart/alternative" or "Multipart/*" , does it mean it has an attachment?

```
public String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {

        if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
            boolean textIsHtml = false;
            String s = (String) p.getContent();
            textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
            return String.valueOf(s);
        }

        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
            // prefer html text over plain text
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            String text = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    if (text == null)
                        text = getText(bp);
                    continue;
                } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                    String s = getText(bp);
                    if (s != null)
                        return String.valueOf(s);
                } else {
                    return getText(bp);
                }
            }
            return text;
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                // fileName = bp.getFileName();
                if (s != null)
                    return String.valueOf(s);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use to parse attachments.  I used to parse with multipart/attachment or multipart/*, and changed to this:

```
            if( mimeMessage.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
            Multipart multipartContent = (Multipart) mimeMessage.getContent();
            List<BodyPart> deleteThese = new ArrayList<BodyPart>();
            for( int i = 0; i < multipartContent.getCount(); i++ ) {
                MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multipartContent.getBodyPart(i);
                String disposition = part.getDisposition();
                if( disposition != null
                        && ( disposition.equalsIgnoreCase( Part.ATTACHMENT )
                        || ( disposition.equalsIgnoreCase( Part.INLINE )
                             && !part.isMimeType( PLAIN_TEXT_MIME_TYPE )
                             && !part.isMimeType( HTML_MIME_TYPE ) )
                ) ) {
                    // do something with part
                }
            }
```

Essentially if an email has a Multipart there is potential for an attachment, but you have to look at the content disposition to really know.  Part.ATTACHMENT would be what you are interested in, and optionally you can ignore or parse the Part.INLINE.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I searched content disposition but there is only set things , I have to receive, get the content disposition. Can you give me lyrics for tutorial or sample please??